# Как открыть на любом локальном компьютере сайт, созданный в iis8 windows server 2012 datacenter?

Tags: azure, azure-websites

Создана виртуальная машина windows sever 2012 datacenter и IIS8. Сайт создан, но он запускается только в браузере виртуальной машины. Вот мои данные:

Имя виртуальной машины - MyFirstSite;

Имя сайта - MyFirstSite.ru; Порт - 8085;

В IIS созданы 2 правила для открытия порта 8085;

На портале azure открыт порт 8085 и dns = ''.

Мне нужно в браузере локального компьютера при вводе "MyFirstSite.ru" открывался мой сайт "MyFirstSite.ru". Подскажите, пожалуйста, что мне надо сделать. Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: 1. Тип сетевого соединения Мост. 2. Прописать в файле hosts ip и доменное имя хоста и гостевой на хосте и гостевой.

Comment: Если можно более подробно написать. Извините за глупые вопросы. Я только учусь, не все понятно. 1. У меня есть 2 ip-адреса: личный и общедоступный. Как и где их использовать ? 2. Как создается сетевое соединения Мост ? 3. Доменное имя хоста это имя сайта, например, "MyFirstSite.ru" ? 4. Что такое гостевой хост ? Очень надеюсь на помощь.

Comment: Виртуальная машина какая! Virtual Box, VMware?

Comment: Виртуальная машина на azure.

Comment: Тип соединения это как виртуальная машина получает адрес. Гостевой хост это виртуальная машина, запущенная на хосте.

Comment: Мой проект доступен по адресу: http://ip-общедоступный адрес/проект/frontend/web. В manager IIS я указываю путь к своему проекту: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\мой проект\frontend\web. Где и находится файл "index.php". В значении ip-адреса пробовал указывать и личный ip (он выводится в подсказке), и "All Unassigned". И порт использую 8085. Настроил правила этого порта и на виртуальной машине, и на компьютере на портале Azure. И web.config поставил по адресу: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\мой проект\frontend\web. Ничего не помогает. Я уже запутался. Если есть идеи как решить проблему, подскажите, пожалуйста.